# Inflating in android

Tags: android

I've looked at so many posts on what inflation is for android and I still don't get it. Can someone describe it in great detail what it is and why I would need it? They say it creates an object out of XML code and can be used or something. I understand almost everything else, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: How can you understand the Android UI if you don't know what inflation in android means...?

Comment: @ JoxTraex rather than commenting make him understand by writing an
answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically to make your logic part different  from  your UI part the concept of XML came.

1- It is easy and very clear to create the UI in XML.

2- By this isolation we have option to create different UI for land/portrait/small/normal/larger modes......

at run time the XML just get parsed and created the object from that.

Answer (score 1):

In Android program structure used MVP ie, view handles both presenter and design ie, layout xml. So we need the define the logic for xml through defining other layouts and often used for maintaining UI manipulation ie, altering the UI behaviour. Thus it made us easy through inflation for loading the layout xml into its corresponding view objects for manipulation.

Through inflation it we are able to access the corresponding UI to the view objects.This everybody known.
Consider scenario in activity class

```
class Activity1 extends Activity{
    setContentView(R.layout.Mainlayout);
    //here we are inflating the 
    //view   into objects actually 
    //its is defined in earlier version as 
    //setContentView(getInflater().inflater(R.layout.MainLayout)
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

But if you write

```
class Activity1 extends Activity{
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//if called then there will be no errror but form runtimeexception Because of absence of setContext()
}
```

Thus for deriving every ui in class we need inflation But the fact is android manufacturer has incorporated the inflation in setContentView(),addview,etc thus the beginner can't understand about inflation It is simple but needs understanding 
we can simply write if  button.xml has only button

```
Button b=(Button)getInflater().inflate(R.layout.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android the [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) is responsible for interpreting an xml layout such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:gravity="center"  
  >

  <WebView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/ticketWeb"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and from the attributes in the xml it will "inflate" or instantiate a java object representation of every item in the xml layout. So if you had a project with this xml file the inflator would create java objects that you could retrieve by using findViewById(). Once you retrieve a reference to those objects you can call their various methods to affect different things about them.